# Generic unmarshalling in Go

Tags: pointers, go, interface, unmarshalling, reflect

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to unmarshal JSON strings to a specific struct, using only the string and the intended type. Here is what I have come up with so far.

Code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func genericUnmarshal(jsonString string, t reflect.Type) interface{} {
    p := reflect.New(t)
    result := p.Interface()
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &result)
    return result
}

func main() {
    jsonData := "{\"name\":\"John\"}"
    unmarshalledPerson := genericUnmarshal(jsonData, reflect.TypeOf(Person{}))

    person := Person{Name: "John"}
    fmt.Printf("struct value: %+v type: %+v\n", person, reflect.TypeOf(person))
    fmt.Printf("unmarshalled value: %+v type: %+v\n", unmarshalledPerson, reflect.TypeOf(unmarshalledPerson))
    fmt.Printf("are variables equal: %v\n", reflect.DeepEqual(unmarshalledPerson, person))
}
```

Returns

```
struct value: {Name:John} type: main.Person
unmarshalled value: &{Name:John} type: *main.Person
are variables equal: false
```

The method `genericUnmarshal` returns a pointer to the type.

My question: Is there a way change the unmarshalled value into a struct (i.e. `Person`) instead of a pointer, so that `reflect.DeepEqual(unmarshalledPerson, person)` returns `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may compare person pointers, because [`reflect.DeepEqual()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual) also accepts if the pointed values are (deeply) equal:

> Pointer values are deeply equal if they are equal using Go's == operator **or if they point to deeply equal values**.

So simply do:

```
fmt.Printf("are variables equal: %v\n",
    reflect.DeepEqual(unmarshalledPerson, &person))
```

Or dereference the `*Person` pointer wrapped inside `unmarshalledPerson` so you get a `Person` struct:

```
fmt.Printf("are variables equal: %v\n",
    reflect.DeepEqual(*unmarshalledPerson.(*Person), person))
```

Both prints `true` (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8t5uZF6JmN7)):

```
are variables equal: true
are variables equal: true
```

Also note that for your "simple" struct you may use simple `==` comparison:

```
*unmarshalledPerson.(*Person) == person
```

This won't be the case if you add other fields such as pointers, structs, maps etc.